# Cannot activate Python virtual environment from within shell script (zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, python, zsh

I cannot activate a Python virtual environment from within a shell script (zsh).
I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/zsh

conda create -n myenv python=3.10

conda activate myenv
```

It sends me the error message that I need to run `conda init`before `conda activate`, but that also does not work.

Has anybody an idea how to make this work?

The goal is to then be able to add `pip install <xyz>` commands into the script, so that overall:

(1) The virtual environment gets created

(2) The virtual environment gets activated

(3) The necessary packages get installed, i.e. `pip install notebook` etc.

All that from running this shell script, i.e. typing `zsh <shellscript>.sh` into the command line.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should quote the entire error. Does it also happen in other shells?